# Non-spin 5-manifold and $2^2$-Bockstein homomorphism

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homological-algebra, differential-topology, manifolds

The $2^2$-Bockstein is $\beta_4$ is associated to
$$0\to\mathbb{Z}/2\to\mathbb{Z}/{8}\to\mathbb{Z}/{4}\to 0,$$

(The $2^n$-Bockstein homomorphism 
$$\beta_{2^n}:H^*(-,\mathbb{Z}/{2^n})\to H^{*+1}(-,\mathbb{Z}/2)$$ is associated to the short exact sequence
$$0\to\mathbb{Z}/2\to\mathbb{Z}/{2^{n+1}}\to\mathbb{Z}/{2^n}\to 0.$$
Note $\beta_2=Sq^1$ is the Steenrod square.)

> **Question**: What are some closed 5-dimensional manifold $M$ satisfy all the criteria below:

1) $M$ is a non-spin manifold.

2) $\beta_{4}$ is nonzero.
$$\beta_{4}:H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}/{4})\to H^{2}(M,\mathbb{Z}/2).$$

3) There exists a *non-zero* generator $a \in H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}/2)$, such that its Poincare dual PD$(a)$ is an orientable 4-manifold.

> If so, what is this sub-manfiold generator $H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}/2)$ and what is the this orientable 4-manifold PD$(a)$? What is this $M$?

Note that the $\mathbb{RP}^5$ satisfies 1) and 2), but it does not satisfy 3), because the PD$(a)$ for $\mathbb{RP}^5$ is a non-orientable 4-manifold $\mathbb{RP}^4$.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $a$? If not, you could let $a = 0$. A Poincaré dual for $0\in H^1(M;\mathbb Z/2)$ is any embedded closed 4-manifold which bounds, such as a small $S^4$ around a point, and this is orientable.

Comment: @Arun, thanks, but $a$ needs to be nonzero.

Comment: Do you also want $M$ to be connected?

Comment: Not necessarily connected, disjoint union is OK. But the connected one is of course better.

Comment: If you are okay with taking connected sums, you can just take $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^5 \# (S^1\times S^4)$. Conditions 1 and 2 are satisfied because of the $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^5$ summand, and for condition 3 you can take $a$ to be the generator of $H^1(S^1)$ in the second summand. Its dual is then the generator of $H_4(S^4)$, and $PD(a)$ is represented by the $S^4$ factor in the second summand.

Comment: @AleksandarMilivojevic Are you sure that $\mathbb{RP}^5$ satisfies condition 2? I think the Lens space $S^5/\mathbb{Z}_4$ satisfies but $\mathbb{RP}^5$ doesn't.

Comment: @Zheyan Wan, it seems to me the map $Z_2 = H^1(RP^5; Z_{2^{n+1}}) \to H^1(RP^5; Z_{2^n}) = Z_2$ is always trivial, and so the nontrivial class in $H^1(RP^5;Z_2)$ has nonzero Bockstein. I’ll admit I didn’t check this originally, and was only going off of what the OP said (that $RP^5$ satisfies conditions 1 and 2).